# card view shadow effect only top side react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

how to set react native android application top side set shadow...
i trey
shadowColor: "#000",
shadowOffset: {
width: 0,
height: 12,
},
shadowOpacity: 0.58,
shadowRadius: 16.00,

elevation: 24,

but cant work in set top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install this librery

```
npm i react-native-drop-shadow
```

```js
import this line
import DropShadow from "react-native-drop-shadow";
```

use this view ginv to shasow

```
 <DropShadow
          style={{
            shadowColor: "#000",
            shadowOffset: {
              width: 0,
              height: 0,
            },
            shadowOpacity: 1,
            shadowRadius: 5,
          }}
        >
    ----- Your  Contain --------------
</DropShadow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using like this

```
    shadowColor: "#000",
shadowOffset: {
    width: 0,
    height: -12,
},
shadowOpacity: 0.58,
shadowRadius: 16.00,

elevation: 24,
  }
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.